# How to use object name and be safe from obfuscation and minification in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, almost every object has a `.name` property, which is a string that is the name of the object itself.

This does exis in some other languages too (like C# for example where you can use `nameof` function to get the name of the object).

Using `.name` can make code cleaner and less prone to inconsistency when renaming objects.

However, when we do that, then in the production environment when the code is minified and obfusticated by build tools, our object's name changes.

For example, consider this function:

```
const getFullName = () => { }

console.log(getFullName.name) // prints 'getFullName'
```

Now in production this might become:

```
const aH = () => { }
console.log(aH.name) // prints 'aH'
```

Is there a way to keep the original `.name` of the object?

Comment: "In JavaScript, almost every object has a `.name` property" is absolutely untrue. Out of the core JS objects only errors and functions have it.

Comment: Also, [according to this article](https://tudorturcu.wordpress.com/2015/07/18/nameof-and-obfuscators/) `nameof` doesn't work with obfuscated .NET either.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, your code shouldn't rely on `Function.prototype.name`'s value if you are using a minifier/build process that mangles names or if you're explicitly obfuscating your code. [This is well documented on MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#javascript_compressors_and_minifiers). (The `Function.prototype.name` property is read-only, too, so you can't just write it at runtime either.)

If you need something other than runtime introspection, your build process probably already has an option to set up [source maps](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps/), but be aware that this allows anyone with access to the source map file to [go back to the original source code](https://github.com/akx/source-from-sourcemaps), thus obviating any obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to keep the original `.name` of the object?

This is what [Source Maps](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps/) are made for:

> Have you ever wished you could keep your client-side code readable and more importantly debuggable even after you've combined and minified it, without impacting performance? Well now you can through the magic of source maps.